# How can two sip users talk to each other by asterisk?

Tags: asterisk

I am using asterisk 13 on centos 6. Now I have add two users in `pjsip.conf` as below:

```
[transport-udp]
type=transport
protocol=udp ;udp,tcp,tls,ws,wss
bind=0.0.0.0


[6001]
type=endpoint
transport=transport-udp
context=from-internal
disallow=all
allow=ulaw
allow=gsm
auth=6001
aors=6001


[6001]
type=auth
auth_type=userpass
password=************
username=6001


[6001]
 type=aor
 max_contacts=1


[7001]
type=endpoint
transport=transport-udp
context=from-internal
disallow=all
allow=ulaw
allow=gsm
auth=7001
aors=7001


[7001]
type=auth
auth_type=userpass
password=************
username=7001


[7001]
 type=aor
 max_contacts=1
```

And I can successfully register 6001 and 7001 from zoiper to asterisk server. But how can I make 6001 and 7001 talk to each other? If I dial 7001 from mobile which regist 6001 account, it returns a 404 error.

I know maybe I need to edit `extensions.conf`, but I do not know how to finish it?

PS: I added this line in `extensions.conf`, but it doesn't work:

```
[from-internal]
exten => 7001,1,Dial(7001)
```

Answer (score 2):

I  got it.

In `extensions.conf`, use this code:

```
exten => 7001,1,Dial(PJSIP/${EXTEN},30)
```

It will work for asterisk 13.

Comment: Please accept your answer so the question is marked as having an accepted answer.